# Setting merged checkpoint as Now checkpoint in Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I'm using Hyper-V 2012 and I've had some checkpoints, which I've merged up until the last before merging it into the original *.vhdx* disk. 
I have 2 files now, a merged *.avhdx* of all the previous checkpoints and a *.vhdx* which is the disk.

I still have all the checkpoints in the checkpoints box in Hyper-V. If I go to the "Now" checkpoint, edit the file path(Virtual hard disk) which points to an old non existing *.avhdx*  since they've been merged and point it to the newly merged *.avhdx*, will it work properly?

Is there another way to merge checkpoints but keep 1 checkpoint to work with the *.vhdx* disk?

Comment: I have to ask why you brought up the questions about old, new, and merged .avhdx files? When Hyper-V is used as it was designed, you can delete and manage checkpoints without any concern or knowledge of the underlying files. So how did we get to this point?

Comment: I got to this point by merging manually. Inspect disk (to find out parenthood) and the merged the disks by editing them. I didn't have time to merge the last checkpoint into the .vhdx , so I wanted to replace disk being used with the last checkpoint - which I did by replacing the .vhdx file with the last .avhdx file as the default disk. After some hours of usage, I turned the Hyper-V off and merged the .avhdx file with the original .vhdx file, removed the .avhdx disk and added a "new disk" - the original .vhdx.

Answer (score 0):

If you've merged the (A)VHDX files manually, the checkpoints that you see in the Hyper-V Manager are now garbage.  You should start fresh, with a new VM.  Note that, if you want to preserve the remaining disk snapshot (which is what's left of your previous checkpoint,) then you'll need to convert it from AVHDX to VHDX so that Hyper-V doesn't automatically merge it the moment that you start the VM.  Never try to manage the files manually.

If you didn't merge the manually, I'm not sure how you ended up in this state.

Comment: I have merged the .avhdx files manually. Using "inspect disk" to find out the order of parenthood. Then I used the "edit disk" and merged to parent (had about 4-5 snapshots - .avhdx files). Probably bad practice, but I don't know how to manage snapshots from the Hyper-V Manager. Do I delete the ones I don't want?

Comment: You have effectively corrupted Hyper-V's database.  As I said above, you need to manually create a new VM and then just delete the old one.

Comment: What I actually did and worked was this: Merged the last .avhdx into the .vhdx, deleted the old checkpoint tree, assigned the new .vhdx disk to the existing VM and booted up. Created a new checkpoint tree and working from there on. Everything seems fine.